# Each line tracer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I am looking for a tracer which can trace each line of code, like holding F11 (step in debugger). After this i want to play steps, and see behavior all threads. Also watch variables in current step. Is there such a tracer?

UDP:

1. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/debugging-net-apps-with-time-travel-debugging-ttd/
2. https://revdebug.com/doc/tutorial/5.0.0.0/activating-revdebug/

Comment: You're describing Visual Studio's debugger. A tracer prints strings provided by the code, not the code's lines.

Comment: Are you looking for a [standalone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-managed-code) or [remote debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019) perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Maybe, but I need to see all the steps. And at every step, variables must be written. I should be able to move in steps, both forward and backward.

Comment: And that's what debuggers do. Not tracers. Going backwards is done using `Time Travel debugging` in Visual Studio. Why aren't you using the debugger for this? Why are you looking for something else?

Comment: If you want to trace the code's execution on a separate machine so you can replay it locally, you need Visual Studio's [Intellitrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/intellitrace?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Intellitrace shows only trace events.

Comment: Not only trace events. What are you asking? Why don't you use a debugger? Whate *else* are you looking for?

Comment: Besides, did you check those links? The Intellitrace link explains how you can record events *and* snapshots to replay an application's execution on your machine

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ku0z2XW.png Only trace event. I need Time Travel Debugging :) Intellitrace can make snaps only in trace event not in each line of code, like this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/debugging-net-apps-with-time-travel-debugging-ttd/. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try Time Travel Debugging, which allow for looking back in time what values had variables at each step. No auto-tracing though. TTD is available in:

- `Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise` as described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-time-travel-debugging-for-visual-studio-enterprise-2019/)
- `Oz Debugger` like [here](https://github.com/oz-code/OzCodeDemo/tree/master/OzCodeDemo/15.TimeTravel)

They are paid tools. I don't know free ones.

Comment: Looks like what I need. But the first only works with Azure?